# How do I get (remote/virtual) repositories to actually show up in Artifactory OSS' repository administration page?

Tags: artifactory

I have an instance of Artifactory OSS (latest version) running in a docker container locally. We have a remote instance of Artifactory (non-OSS) running as well.

In my **local** instance, I set up a **remote repository** of package type Ivy pointing to each of the repositories we have set up in our remote non-OSS instance.

Once I have created a remote repository configuration, I can view each remote repository I created and its artifacts being served under the Application --> Artifactory --> Artifacts page **HOWEVER** under the Administration --> Repositories --> Repositories page where I am expecting to be able to make changes to the configurations (I have logged in as Admin with administrator privileges btw), *none of the repositories I set up are actually visible here!* I only see a **0 Repositories** count and a **No remote repositories** message where I am expecting to see a list.

When I do Ivy resolves against my local (remote repository) it works as expected, so they're definitely working... just not showing up for administration.

I have tried rolling back to earlier versions of Artifactory OSS but that hasn't changed anything.

I can tediously work around this with a combination of the REST API and the UI but I REALLY JUST want to be able to administer the configurations within the web app... Am I just being dumb about something or is there a known issue regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce it on my end on as well on version 7.19.1, seems this issue happens when working with Ivy on Artifactory OSS.

I have opened a [bug](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-25988) for this on JFrog Jira.